# DNS resolve stopped working after 19.10 update

Tags: networking, server, dns, 19.10

I have this rather curious problem I have no idea how to debug -- I've updated a server from 19.04 to 19.10, and now the server cannot do DNS queries any more. For instance:

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find google.com: SERVFAIL
```

It runs a bridge interface, on which two VMs run. Inside the VMs, everything is working fine. When I restart `systemd-resolve` after the machine has booted up, DNS immediately starts to work. The only change was the update from 19.04 to 19.10 (and this server has been updated from an old version of Ubuntu continuously.) I'm not sure what can be going wrong, the logs for `systemd-resolved` don't look any different than they used to.

The network config:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_fd 5
    bridge_stp yes
```

`systemd-resolve --status` before I restart indicates no DNS:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 11 (vnet1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 10 (vnet0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 9 (virbr0-nic)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 8 (virbr0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 7 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 6 (br0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 5 (eno4)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 4 (eno3)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (eno2)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

After I restart it, I get the right DNS:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.178.2
         DNS Servers: 192.168.178.2
          DNS Domain: lan
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 11 (vnet1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 10 (vnet0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 9 (virbr0-nic)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 8 (virbr0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 7 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 6 (br0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 5 (eno4)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 4 (eno3)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (eno2)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (eno1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

```
iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1959 packets, 333K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1959  333K LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2609  940K LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2609  940K LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2609  940K LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2609  940K DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2609  940K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2609  940K ACCEPT     all  --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1462 packets, 209K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1470  212K LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2609  940K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2609  940K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
```

Comment: I suspect that systemd wants netplan and not /etc/network/interfaces. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: If so, why would it work when I just restart it? Also, thanks :)

Comment: I was using the same sort of bridge-configuration here (for a KVM-QEMU virtual machine), and had the same problem on the host machine after the 19.10 upgrade (VMs could communicate fine). Rebooting didn't help for me though. After removing the bridge, found a work-around by connecting the VM's NIC to the host device in VEPA mode, since I don't need host-to-guest networking, but using a bridge was better.

Comment: Just tried setting up a bridge via `netplan`, using [this page](https://webby.land/2018/04/27/bridging-under-ubuntu-18-04/) to guide me. It worked, I have my bridge back. :-)

Comment: Interesting -- I'll give it a try then!

Comment: That seems to have done the trick for me as well -- would you mind adding this as an answer, so I can accept it :) ?